# Alertmanager never sends e-mail and never uses my receiver configured with e-mail

Tags: docker, email, alert, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a docker running an alertmanager. I have severals receiver in my alertmanager.yml which sends alerts to teams, slacks successfully ... but alertmanager doesn't send any e-mail and neither use the receiver configured with the e-mail

My configuration looks like this ..
'teams-notif' is working : i am receiving alerts in Teams
'mail-notif' doesn't do anything and idk why ..

```
global:
smtp_smarthost: "192.168.1.1:25"
smtp_from: "test@test.com"

templates: 
- /etc/alertmanager/templates/*.tmpl

# The root route on which each incoming alert enters.
route:
group_by: [ "alertname", "cluster", "service" ]
group_wait: 30s # How long to wait to send a notification for a new group of alerts.
group_interval: 1m # How long to wait before sending a notification about new alerts that are added to an existing group of alerts.
repeat_interval: 3h 

# A default receiver
receiver: default-group


routes:

  - receiver: 'mail-notif'
    group_by: ["hostname", "alertname"]
    repeat_interval: 1h
    group_wait: 0s
    group_interval: 1s

  - receiver: 'teams-notif'
    group_by: ["hostname", "alertname"]
    repeat_interval: 1h
    group_wait: 0s
    group_interval: 1s

receivers:

- name: mail-notif
  email_configs:
    - to: 'myself@test.com'


- name: teams-notif
  webhook_configs:
    - url: "http://192.1.1.1:2001/TEAMS_INCOMING_WEBHOOK_URL_TEST"
      send_resolved: true
```

the smtp is correctly configured. I tested the telnet inside the docker, everything is ok. I already tested locally using swaks and I received the test e-mail from the server

Moreover when I am trying to check to docker alertmanager, it returns nothing

`docker logs alertmanager 2>&1 | grep mail-notif` 
Any idea please ?

---

**Edit:** Thanks @markalex I think I was just missing `continue: true` !

Now I can see this in logs:

```
caller=notify.go:743 level=debug component=dispatcher receiver=teams-test-sendmail integration=email[0] msg="Notify success" attempts=1
```

I also put `smtp_require_tls` to false

But I am still not receiving any alert. Do I have to use a template or not?

Comment: If memory serves, go (in which alertmanaer is written) is not happy with unencrypted smtp servers other than localhost. (I assume port 25 implies that it's unencrypted). Could you check it out?

Comment: One more thing: in config you provided neither of routes have any matchers. I'm not 100% confident on it, but I'd assume since no `continue` is provided alert will be sent to first satisfactory route (I'm not sure why it is the last one in your case).

Comment: Templates are optional, in sense that there is a default template that will be applied, if no template is specified in config. Since you can see "Notify success" in logs - aletrmanager have sent an email, and no error occurred. Investigate on the mail server side if message has been received, and why it wasn't delivered to a recipient.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will investigate on Monday. I will try to find out why I am not receiving any email because when I am trying with the swaks command, Everything is ok

Comment: Well .. It's resolved
I just apply continue: true and  smtp_require_tls: false .. then everything is working .. No SMTP relay issue anymore :) thanks a lot !